# How to upgrade php 5.4.40 to 5.6 in centos 6 32 bit?

Tags: php, linux, centos, upgrade

I have this error in my log :

> Headers and client library minor version mismatch. Headers:50531 Library:50625

I found out I have to upgrade my php version. I tried some way to update and it's not upgraded.

Comment: Are you running WHM with your centos build ?

Comment: no.i use direct admin on dedicated server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With direct admin you will need to access `/usr/local/directadmin/custombuild/`

once in the directory access this file with a text editor: `options.conf`

Change the required values and run the below commands.

```
cd /usr/local/directadmin/custombuild
./build update
./build apache
./build php d
```

Alternatively you can set it like this:

```
cd /usr/local/directadmin/custombuild
./build set php5_ver 5.3
./build set mysql 5.1
./build update
./build clean
./build apache d
./build php d
./build mysql d
```

To rebuild zend:

```
cd /usr/local/directadmin/custombuild
./build zend
```

If you encounter that zend is already installed read through this post about removing lines from your php.ini file: https://forum.directadmin.com/showthread.php?t=43301

Courtesy of the directadmin forums.

Comment: i got this errors in Log after update : [Fri Jul 17 12:00:44.946983 2015] [:error] [pid 14346] [client 91.106.70.121:42686] Failed loading /usr/local/lib/ioncube_loader_lin_5.4.so: /usr/local/lib/ioncube_loader_lin_5.4.so: undefined symbol: zend_unmangle_property_name
[Fri Jul 17 12:00:44.947143 2015] [:error] [pid 14346] [client 91.106.70.121:42686] Zend Guard Loader requires Zend Engine API version 220100525.
[Fri Jul 17 12:00:44.947184 2015] [:error] [pid 14346] [client 91.106.70.121:42686] The Zend Engine API version 220121212 which is installed, is newer.
[Fri Jul 17 12:00:44.947230 2015]

Comment: i have this message to rebuild zend : File already exists:    ZendOptimizer-3.3.3-linux-glibc23-i386.tar.gz
There is no Zend Guard loader available for PHP 5.5